# Is there FreeBSD-based equivalent of SmartOS or opennode?

Tags: virtualization, freebsd, kvm-virtualization

Both SmartOS and opennode seem to do the same thing:

- take a kernel and basic OS installation
- add OS-level virtualization possiblity
- add true virtualization possibility
- add management

SmartOS is based on Solaris fork, opennode on linux (CentOS).

Is there something like the above, based on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 3):

FreeBSD has [Jails](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails.html), which is basically OS-level virtualization (the original inspiration for Solaris [Zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers)).
This functionality is built in to the operating system, and wouldbe "os-level virtualization" (in the sense that you can run several 'virtual' FreeBSD systems on one host).

There are [tools in the ports collection to manage/work with jails](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=Jail&stype=all) which implement varying degrees of management on top of the basic `jail` subsystem - lots of articles/blog entries around the net have been written on these tools and will give you a good idea of how they work / what they can do, but there's no substitute for installing one and banging around.

---

As far as I'm aware there's no true (bare-metal simulating, VMWare-style) virtualization based on FreeBSD.  You can hack something together with QEMU/VirtualBox, but if you need mutliple-OS bare-metal-simulating virtualization you're probably better off with VMWare's ESXi (free or fully-licensed depending on your needs), or Microsoft's Hyper-V platform...

Comment: Thanks. I asked more in the line of "complete platform with jails as well as (more direct, kvm-style) full virtualization) and management. But it seems there is nothing like that (qjail etc. but its parts). It can probably emerge when bhyve is finished?